# With enough money to buy 20 mangoes or 30 oranges, if one wants to buy an equal amount of each, how many to buy?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's a question in my math book. A man had enough money to buy 20 mangoes or 30 oranges. If he wants to buy an equal amount of each, how many would he buy? I don't really care about the answer, just how to get it. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think that you have enough information to solve it. Check again, perhaps you are given something more. (or I am wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  He has $x$ dollars.  A mango costs $\frac x{20}$, while an orange costs $\frac x{30}$.  So a (mango + orange) costs how much?  How many (mango + orange)s can he buy?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid. When you add up x/20 + x/30 you get 5x/60. 5x/60=x? I still don't get it.

Comment: Divide the amount of money available by the cost: $x \div \frac{5x}{60}$.

Comment: Correct, you get $\frac {5x}{60}=\frac x{12}$.  With $x$ dollars you can buy $12$ of those.

Answer (score 0):

Love the (mango + orange) solution. A mechanical solution:

Let $x$ be the amount of money he has. Let $m$ be price of one mango. Let $r$ be price of one orange. Suppose he can just buy $n$ of each fruit. Then
$$nm +nr = x\,.$$
We know 20 mangoes cost $x$ so $m = x/20$. Likewise $r = x/30$. So we have 
$$\frac{nx}{20} + \frac{nx}{30} = x\,.$$
The $x$'s cancel, so
$$\frac{n}{20} + \frac{n}{30} = 1\,.$$
Solve for $n$. The form of the result points to the  (mango + orange) solution.